# Add css to users magento

Tags: css, magento, php

I Guess this would be possible, but how? I need to add additional CSS only to users/customers that are logged into our webshop. Via XML or Phtml?

Stian

Comment: can you please be more specific?

Comment: Whenever a user is logged into the webshop, i need another css file to be added. There is some CSS code that really do not need to be included unless user is logged in which i would like to move to its own file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding

```
<customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/user.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
```

Into template`s local.xml will load that file when customers are logged in.